# H1 tag overtop of the menu

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, wordpress, responsive

Here is the website that I am making: http://oca.darkstarmedia.net/about/a-history-of-the-oca/

The problem is the `h1` tag is over the dropdown menu. This only happens on the iPhone not on an emulator.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
What have you tried? It's likely a parent element of the `h1` mixed with some `z-index` with positioned elements.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just have to set the `z-index` property of the dropdown higher than the `h1` tag. Note that `z-index` only works if the element it is being applied to has its `position` property set. Here's an example:

```
.dropdown {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 50;
}
```

Here's a link to learning more about `z-index`: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Good luck!

Comment: I have z-inidex:1000; at dropdown class. Moreover it shows well on chrome or anyother web browser but only Iphone shows like the picture way.

Comment: Hmm...Sometimes `z-index` is a bit buggy on iOS. Try using `transform:translateZ(1px);` instead.